# How to join a team in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a hide and seek map. To do this, the killer must be on team 'Blue'. I put in this command:

```
/scoreboard teams join red @p
```

And the command block says

> Could not add 1 player(s) to team red.

I am curious why it isn't working as it doesn't give me a reason. Does anyone know the cause? How do I fix it? What do I need to do?

Comment: did you add team red already? aka does team red exist?

Comment: "It's like someone on stack exchange saying 'Hey my game is not booting up how do I fix it?'" Then why do you imitate that? Give more details! What did you try, what other team related commands did you use in that world previously, ... Also, you seem to know SE, but you also use poor grammar, so you're hard to judge: What's your level of command experience?

Answer (score 1):

In order to join a team the team in question must already exist.

First create a team (or more):
`/scoreboard teams add <name> <display_name>` (display name is optional)

You can as well list your current teams to check what's already there:
`/scoreboard teams list`

And if you use the list command with a team name you can check what players are on that particular team:
`/scoreboard teams list <name>`

If you have your teams you can then finally add entities to them...
You can use selectors [@a, @p,..] for the entity or even leave it blank (in that case the executor will join the team)
`/scoreboard teams join <name> <entity>`